# check number of child of current category magento

Tags: magento, categories

in magento ,check number of sub category of current category in category page

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->load($id);
```

$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

by using this code we have get chil category but we want to check number of sub category of current category in magento

Answer (score 0):

This code is not proper,
Please used below codes,This code is apply in category and catalog search page

```
    if(Mage::registry('current_category'))
    {
    $cat=Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
    /* used for category level*/
    }
    else{
    $cat=2; // 2 is root category id
    /* used for serch level*/
    }
    $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat)->getChildren();
echo count($cats);
```

Or ,any place

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',$cat_id);

echo count($collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope, following code will work for you:-

$sizeOfSubCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $parentId)->getSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `count($cat->getChildren());` to get count of children categories.